# Cocoa dynamic swap view

Tags: iphone, macos

I've struggled with this problem for months and know there has to be a simple solution

I'm trying to use a View area within an existing view, designed in interface builder, and want to dynamically change it with another nib designed view. I want to instantiate the views from the extra nib on demand In my controllers and not have them preinstantiated.

I'm sure it's simple but just can't find the solution I need

Many thanks in advance

### Edit

Edited as I can't answer my own question today

I can't believe it was so simple. First I empty the subview and then add the subview I want. Instantiating is just the initWithNibNamed as expected.

The solution can be found in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html looking in MyWindowController.m

Comment: Is your target Mac OS or iOS? You’ve added tags for both.

Comment: It's both platforms. I assumed there is a heavy similarity between the 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited as I can't answer my own question today

I can't believe it was so simple. First I empty the subview and then add the subview I want. Instantiating is just the initWithNibNamed as expected.

The solution can be found in http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html looking in MyWindowController.m

Comment: Copied/pasted to provide an answer, else others will waste time trying to answer an answered question

Comment: good move. However, I have flagged so a mod can turn this into a CW.